# powershell script to add text to existing aspx file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find resources to help me write a powershell script to add text to an existing aspx file but can't seem to find anything. Does anybody have any suggestions or is there anybody that can help me some other way?

Update: So it's out there, I'm using version 1.0.

I have:

```
$lines = Get-Content foo.aspx

$lines = "<head>asfdsfsafd</head>" + $lines

$lines | Out-File "c:\documents and settings\...\foo.aspx" -Encoding utf8
```

but it wipes out everything originally in foo.aspx and creates `<head>asfdsfsafd</head><head>asfdsfsafd</head>`. How do I fix it so it keeps the original stuff in foo and add stuff to the beginning of the file rather than end?

Update:

I've figured out how to add text with:

```
$lines = add-content -path "C:\Documents and Settings\..\foo.aspx" -value "Warning...."
```

but want the text to go at the beginning of the aspx file

Update: I found a function that does what I want and I'm all set.

Comment: That is weird. Why do you want this? Could you explain it? Wouldn't be more easy to make an aspx file that reads text from a database and create something (ideally another aspx) that updates text in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the content (array of strings) of the ASPX file using `Get-Content`:

```
$lines = Get-Content foo.aspx
```

Or you can get the content as a single string which is sometimes more useful if you want to use a regex that spans lines:

```
$content = Get-Content foo.aspx -raw
```

As far as changing the content, you have all sorts of options:

```
$content = "text before " + $content
$content += "text after"
$content = $content -replace 'regex pattern','replacement text'
```

And then to write back out to the file:

```
$content | Out-File foo.aspx -Encoding <UTF8 or ASCII or UNICODE>
```

Comment: When I run `$lines = Get-Content foo.aspx` it gives me everything, as you said. However, when I run `$content = Get-Content foo.aspx -raw` I get `Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'raw'. At C:\....`

Comment: I think I found my answer and it's because `raw` is for a different version than what I'm using. I'm using version 1.0. Is there a command I can use for this version that is equivalent?

Comment: 1.0 really?  :-)  You can use `$content = [io.file]::ReadAllText("$pwd\foo.aspx")`.

Comment: That works but it does what `Get-Content foo.aspx` does and gives me everything. It's not spanning lines?

Comment: Yes, it gives you everything but as a single string object and not as an array of strings (one per line).  Which do you need?

Comment: I'd like an array of strings (one per line)

Comment: Ah, then just use `$content = Get-Content foo.aspx`.

Comment: I'm a little lost. When you say a single string object, you mean lines running together right? Also, with your `-replace` example, aren't you missing a `'`. And the `regex pattern` would be whatever was originally there that I want to replace it with using `replacement text` right?

Comment: Yeah there was a quote missing - fixed.  And yeah, replacement text replaces what is specified by regex pattern.  WRT single string object, yes every line, separated by CRLF chars, is put into a single string.  That is necessary if you have regex that matches text across separate lines.

Comment: I don't have a 1.0 system to test on but we are prepending a string to an array of strings ($lines).  That works in v4.  In v1 perhaps not.  Make sure you reset your aspx file to whatever was in there before and try this `$lines[0] = "<head>asfdsfsafd</head>" + $lines[0]`.  Then output $lines back to the aspx file.